# Express.js request body __proto__

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a little problem with request.body generated by express.urlencoded() middleware. In some cases it adds `__proto__` at the end of request.body object and than it can't be used directly to initiate moongose model like so `var user = new User(req.body)`

As an example I'll use [node-express-mongoose-demo](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo) repository. All forms works just fine but `app.post('/users', users.create)` recieves req.body "polluted" with `__proto__`

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem comes from the `urlencoded` middleware, the one which is included with `Express 3`.

A possible solution is not to use the Express bodyParser, but the `body-parser` module.

Instead of

```
app.use(express.urlencoded())
```

you can write

```
var bodyparser = require('body-parser')

..........

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded())
```

The problem seems to come from the `qs` module (the version used by `express 3` module). It forces to add a `__proto__` on the objects it builds. The last version does not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this is interesting. `__proto__` is a special/automatic/internal property on all objects in some javascript implementations including node/v8. I haven't seen mongoose do this type of thing though. The code to convert the attributes passed to a model constructor to the model/document instance [is here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/6213379ed3b51d875880e4d87ae6577f3375ca4c/lib/document.js#L127). I don't see anything suspicious there though.

Do you know exactly which cases this happens, and are you sure it is `urlencoded` doing it? What happens when you try to save a user that has been "polluted" with this? Normally mongoose would just ignore fields that are not defined in the schema, so what happens?

You should be able (maybe?) to work around this with a middleware as below, but I'm curious to really isolate and understand the root cause. underscore/lodash has `omit` which works well here.

```
var _ = require('lodash');

function unpollute(req, res, next) {
  req.body = _.omit(req.body, '__proto__');
  next();
}
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(unpollute);
```

Then when your route handler is run, `req.body` won't have `__proto__`.

Comment: This workaround will work as well as recreating body object like so: `var fields = Object.create(req.body)` but do you actually know why sometimes __proto__ is added and sometimes not?

Comment: I don't see anything weird in how the object is created, so I'm not sure where `req.body.proto` comes from, but perhaps some other middleware in your app is tainting it?  https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/7edb875a9f305e38f4d960fa46ac674038241892/lib/middleware/urlencoded.js#L47

Comment: I've found out that `__proto__` is not added when form has attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. So multipart middleware is not producing additional key.

Comment: When you try to initiate moongose model with "polluted" req.body you end up with Error 500 `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined` in [mongoose/lib/document.js line 449](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/document.js#L449)

Answer (score 0):

*I know it's 5 years now since the question was asked, but actually I hit that same problem yesterday.*

I have good news to share - looks like **mongoose 5.3.9** actually solves this. You can create new model using object that contains `__proto__`. Not sure if that will persist in future, though.

Also, the qs module can be upgraded to recent version to solve this problem too.

Code used to test:

```
// simulate object creation by express
let newCustomer = Object.create(null);
newCustomer.name = 'new test customer';
newCustomer.__proto__ = Object.prototype;

console.log(newCustomer); // { name: 'new test customer', __proto__: {} }
Customer.create(newCustomer, function(err, created) {
    console.log('err:', err, 'created:', created);
    // mongose 5.3.8: ValidationError: Customer validation failed
    // mongose 5.3.9: new customer created
})
```

A bit more details:

The **proto** is problematic because qs module creates new object using:

```
Object.create(null)
```

Then when the `restoreProto` is invoked it tries to fix the prototype of object:

```
obj.__proto__ = Object.prototype;
```

And the `__proto__` ends up as visible property of object:

```
let obj = Object.create(null);
obj.__proto__ = Object.prototype;
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
// [ '__proto__' ]
```

If the new object is created with `{}` or even `Object.create(Object)` then the `__proto__` does not appear in key enumeration, even if assigned in the same way:

```
let obj = {};
obj.__proto__ = Object.prototype;
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
// []
```

Interesting fact - this behavior has changed over time. In node v0.10.28 both code snippets (well, with var instead of let ;)) produce empty array.

Another interesting thing is that newer version of qs module creates object in different way so it's no longer causing this problem.