# node js express __proto__ added to req.query

Tags: node.js, express

I have a very strange thing happening with Nodejs / Express where express appears to be appending [__ proto __] to some of the request query object variables.

This is the data sent via a request:

```
GET /?COMPLETED=N&func=stop&devs[COAT]=4&empid=10000024 200 9141ms - 197b
```

And this is what express is producing:

```
{ 
  COMPLETED: 'N',
  func: 'stop',
  devs: { COAT: '4', [__proto__]: {} },
  empid: '10000024'
}
```

I have googled this and not found any solutions, there is also another question posted here ([Express.js request body __proto__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776491/express-js-request-body-proto)) but no obvious solution that I can see ?

Comment: Which version of express is it? I dont get the `__proto` part in express  `4.13.0`

Comment: Neither do I with both Express 3 and 4.

Comment: How are you using the req.query? And which node version?